# Rails: get records for has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

How would I rewrite this request to get the `articles` available to the `current_user` if `articles` and `templates` have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship? I feel like I'm close but I can't quite figure it out.

```
current_user.brand.articles.joins(:template).where(:templates => { :id => @template.id })
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the `brand` association represents and posting your models would go a long way to help figure this out, but here's a guess:

```
current_user.brand.articles.joins(:templates).where(:templates => { :id => @template.id })
```

You were pluralizing `templates` in the where clause but not in the join.